# Python Excel Reformatting

Tags: python, excel, formatting

Recently I have been working with an excel sheet for work and I need to format it in a certain way (shown below). The following is the excel sheet I'm working with (apologies for the REDACTED, some of the information is sensitive, also apologize for the image, I am fairly new to Stack Overflow and do not know how to add excel data):

[image: CurrentFormat]

Above is the format that I currently am using, but I need to convert the data to the following format:

[image: DesiredFormat]

As you can see I need the data to go from 10 lines, down to 1 line per unique LBREFID. I have already tried to use different Pandas functions such as .tolist() and .pivot() for the data, but that would result in data that does not resemble the desired format. This is an interesting problem that I, unfortunately, do not have the time to solve. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
import pandas._testing as tm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tests = ["BMCELL", "PLASMA", "NEOPLASMABM", "NEOPLASMATBM", "CD138", "CD56", "CYCLIND1", "KAPPA", "LAMBDA", "NEOPLASMA"]
df = load_workbook(filename='GregFileComparison\\NovemberData.xlsx')
sheet = df['Sheet1']
i = 0
a = 3
e = 11
while (i <= 227):
  for row in sheet['A' + str(a) + ':E' + str(e)]:
    for cell in row:
      cell.value = None
  for row in sheet['I' + str(a) + ':J' + str(e)]:
    for cell in row:
      cell.value = None
  for row in sheet['M' + str(a) + ':N' + str(e)]:
    for cell in row:
      cell.value = None
  a += 10
  e += 10
  i += 1
sheet.delete_cols(12)
sheet.delete_cols(7)
i = 11
while (i <= 19):
  sheet.insert_cols(i)
  i += 1
counter = 10
i = 0
while (i <= 9):
  sheet.cell(row=1, column=counter).value = tests[i]
  counter += 1
  i += 1
j = 0
i = 3
counter = 1
while (j <= 250):
  while (counter <= 9):
    sheet.move_range("J" + str(i), rows=-(counter), cols=counter)
    i += 1
    counter += 1
  j += 1
  counter = 0
sheet.delete_cols(6)
sheet.delete_cols(6)
df.save('output.xlsx')```

I found that hardcoding the transformations on the excel sheet worked best.
````